# CSS keyframe animation not working on an SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

Please see:

http://codepen.io/richardstelmach/pen/RNwvyG

"svg" is the id of the  in the html.

The CSS is:

```
#svg{
  display:block;
  max-height:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  animation:filters 2s infinite;
}

#svg .colour1{
  fill:#2bb0b7;
}

#svg .colour2{
  fill:#ab3e41;
}

/* animate effects */

@keyframes filters {
  0%{ 
    filter:hue-rotate(0deg); 
  }
  100% { 
    filter:hue-rotate(360deg); 
  }
}
```

The animation isn't working. I've tried changing it to specific -webkit- CSS and also tried applying it to the class ".colour1" instead but to no avail.

I also tried animating the fill instead of using the hue-rotate. But again, no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Just add vendor prefix and its beautiful:

```
@keyframes filters {
  0%{ 
    -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(0deg); 
  }
  100% { 
    -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(360deg); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Note that 'animation' also needs a prefix for older versions of webkit browsers. Ideally, sadly the above needs various prefixes at the moment. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix your filters too:

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwwwaY)

```
@-webkit-keyframes filters {
  0%{ 
    -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(0deg); 
  }
  100% { 
    -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(360deg); 
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's great. I must not have prefixed everything. Shame, i thought it would have been compatible by now.

Answer (score 0):

Basically needed to browser prefix everything. :

```
#svg{
  display:block;
  max-height:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  -webkit-animation:filters 20s infinite;
}

#svg .colour1{
  fill:#2bb0b7;
}

#svg .colour2{
  fill:#ab3e41;
}

/* animate effects */

@-webkit-keyframes filters{
  0%{ 
    -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(0deg); 
  }
  100% { 
    -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(360deg); 
  }
}
```

Finished code here: http://codepen.io/richardstelmach/pen/RNwvyG

Will need to add in other pre-fixes for other browsers.

Comment: You do not need to prefix everything just the filter propriety. Browsers that support -webkit-filter will have unprefixed animations

Comment: i tried taking the -webkit- prefix off the animation property but it then didn't work (in google chrome version 38). According to this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation. It only works with the prefix which explains it. The latest version of chrome would work without the prefix.